# Java problems each time I try to import a project to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have purchased 3 Android games source codes, but when I import any of them to eclipse I get these two errors :

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
>
> the type java.lang.object cannot be resolved. it is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

When I add the JRE library by clicking right on the project and build path => Configure Build Path => library => add library => JRE System library => Workspace Default jre. I just get more than 400 another error, most are like this : ... cannot be resolved to a type/variable.

Checked for all possible solutions but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm going to guess you need to add more to your build path.

Comment: "I am new to eclipse"... Worth pointing out that Eclipse is not recommended for any Android development

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the JRE System Library from the project and then add it back again. 
Here are the steps:

1. Go to properties of project (right click > Properties)
2. View the "Libraries" tab in the "Build Path" section
3. Find the "JRE System Library" in the list
4. Remove the "JRE System Library"
5. Click "Add Library ...", Select "JRE System Library" and add the appropriate JRE for the project (eg. 'Workspace default JRE')
6. Click "Finish" in the library selection and "OK" in the project properties and then wait for the re-build of the project

Another steps you may do is trying to clean the project to force it to build again.

Here is a link with more info:
http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html

Comment: Already tried this solution ... never works for me unfortunatly.